# Application.Ontime seems to stop global event handling

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have a global event handler in my Excel add-in which catches double-click events. This works perfectly UNTIL I call `Application.OnTime`. After this, the global event handler just stops working.
I have tried putting an `Application.EnableEvents = True` into the `Sub` that is called by `OnTime` just in case, but it doesn't help.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around this by reinitializing my global event handler right after the `Application.OnTime` is called. However, if anyone can explain why this happens, I would still like to understand.

So I first initialize in the `workbook_open` event in ThisWorkbook

```
Dim XLApp As mdlAppEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set XLApp = New mdlAppEvents
End Sub
```

And then in the module containing the Sub that is called by `Application.OnTime` I dim the variable again, and set it again in the Sub that's called.

```
Dim XLApp As mdlAppEvents

Sub Process()
    nextRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime nextRun, "SomeCode"
End Sub

Sub SomeCode()
    //some code...
    Set XLApp = New mdlAppEvents
End Sub
```